# Stop loss does not trigger correctly if the very next candle moves against us more than stop distance

Tags: pine-script

I have a strategy that opens a long position with 100% of my capital if the last candle closes above the 4 MA. I set a stop loss at 1% below the average entry price, in this case the entry was at 1152 so the stop loss is set at 1152 * 0.99 which is 1140.48. 
[image: Stop loss not triggering if next candle moves against us a lot]
Desired behavior is that I enter at 1152 with a stop loss that triggers **as soon as price goes down past 1140.48**.

I get stopped out at the **next candle open price** at 1005.5 for a 12.72% loss. I have tried reducing order size but it makes no difference, the position is exited at the same place. Is this something to do with the time that Pine calculates the script? It seems to be a problem when the **very next candle** opens at more distance from entry than my stop loss distance.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Stoploss", overlay=true, 
  default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

sma_per = input(4, title='SMA Lookback Period', minval=1)
sl_inp = input(1.0, title='Stop Loss %', type=input.float) / 100

sma = sma(close, sma_per)
stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)

strategy.entry("L", strategy.long, when=close > sma)
// Stop loss should trigger whenever we hit stop_level once we are in a position
strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "L", stop=stop_level) 

plot(sma, color=color.orange, linewidth=2)
```

Note that I also tried using:

```
strategy.order("Stop Loss", long=strategy.short, qty=strategy.position_size, stop=stop_level)
```

for my stop loss instead of `strategy.exit()` but I get the same result.

Here is the trade list, displaying our loss. note that the same thing happens with Trade 2 - we lose more than we should on the very next candle:[image: Trade list showing stop loss did not work]

I understand that Pine calculates the script after each candle close and if I set `calc_on_order_fills` to true then the script will also be ran after an order is filled. This seems to fix the problem since once I enter a long position, the script is ran again on the current candle and triggers the stop loss if price moves against me enough. However, this also results in the whole script being ran every time an order is filled. Is there any way to simply have the following behavior?

1. Enter position according to last candle close if entry  condition is met
2. Set stop loss according to entry position
3. Stop loss is triggered **any time after entering** the position if price hits stop loss level

Comment: pls what this video about why we should avoid the 'calc on order fills' option https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BwFMH7PaCc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating `stop_level` using `strategy.position_avg_price` in your formula.
Let us say your Entry condition is met on Candle 1. The position will open on the next candle (candle 2), and therefore, in the Candle 1 where you are placing the Entry and Exit orders, the `stop_level` will be NaN.

It will be properly calculated using the position's average price only on the candle where the entry order has filled (candle 2). The Exit order will have its stop price updated thereafter, which will be applicable from the subsequent candle (candle 3).
Therefore, on candle 2 where you have entered, you have no stop loss at all. The stop order becomes applicable only from candle 3 onwards. This is quite risky where the entry candle goes against your expected direction.

I have faced a similar situation in my strategy too. The only way to get around is to place a temporary stop loss for that candle, using some approximation. For instance, you can use the close of Candle 1 to calculate the stop loss, as follows.

```
stop_level = (strategy.position_avg_price == 'NaN') ? (close * (1 - sl_inp)) : (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp))
```

This way, for the entry candle, you would have at least some stop, which will correct itself from Candle 3 onwards to the exact stop as per the entry price.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the next code is supposed to work as you need, but at some bars it exits at the same price and I can't find the reason yet. But I hope the code will be helpful to you.

```
//@version=4
strategy("Stoploss", overlay=true)

sma_per = input(4, title='SMA Lookback Period', minval=1)
sl_inp = input(1.0, title='Stop Loss %', type=input.float) / 100.0


var nextTickToEntry = false

stop_level = 0.0
if nextTickToEntry
    nextTickToEntry := false
    stop_level := open * (1 - sl_inp)
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "L", stop=stop_level)
plot(stop_level)


if close > sma(close, sma_per)
    strategy.entry("L", strategy.long)
    nextTickToEntry := true
```

Comment: Hi Michel, I tried your code but I'm getting the same behavior. It's not only on the candle in my image, it happens every time the next candle moves against the position to a greater value than the stop distance. It is as if the stop loss code has no effect until the candle we entered at has finished printing, at which point it is too late and we are forced to be stopped out at the next open price.